# cannot import images

Tags: magento2, import, product-images

[image]I'm trying to import csv products but I get that error

```
1. Imported resource (image) could not be downloaded from external resource due to timeout or access permissions in row(s): 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

although the Images File Directory field  is `pub\media\import

image is from csv file

Comment: Set your images path location here Admin > System > Import > Images File Directory - https://prnt.sc/me6cnk (For Example set it var/import). Upload all images in this magentoroot/var/import folder. for example Your image directory full path magentoroot/var/import/9/1.jpg

Comment: Check my above comment.

Comment: @SaneerLadani same problem

Answer (score 0):

While importing, magento looks at images in the **pub/media/import** folder, but I left it as empty so instead it will throw the error I previously mentioned. After copying the image into **pub/media/import** after you can check it .

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: you can copy all images this directory `pub/media/import`

Comment: I know, all images I need are there

Comment: I tried to left it empty and I get same error

Comment: currently all images here available or not?

Comment: yes available there

Comment: @YomnaMansour what are exact file path location?

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\project\pub\media\import

Comment: @YomnaMansour check my comment at your question sections and follow it